# Sharpening hedge trimmer blades

Tags: sharpening

What is the best type of rotary tool bits for sharpening hedge trimmer blades. The stone grinding bits don't seem durable enough.

Comment: Per https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvFLD-6TI5Y an angle grinder seems to do wonders along with a good file.

Comment: If you mean "like a Dremel" rotary tool, it's the wrong tool for tis job.

Comment: I use a 4” grinder and flapper disks (sandpaper flaps) I find the finer disks provide a better edge but grind lightly don’t force it and over heat the metal or it will loose the temper I do the same on my hay cutting bar (same thing as a hedge trimmer moving cutter and a fixed one).

Comment: Why are we all putting answers in comments? Did the brain fairy make us forget how SO works? :D